# Free software or OS for web usage reports / network traffic analytics-statistics

Tags: networking, statistics, analytics

I run a small network for my big family, where about 50 devices connect. Line capacity: 50Mbps downlink / 10Mbps uplink.

I am searching for a free software or operating system where I can have reports and analytics of web usage / application usage / network traffic. I have a free PC with 2 network cards so it can act like a gateway to capture traffic.

I want to know:

• Traffic down/up per device (per IP or per MAC address) 
• Traffic per apps (e.g 1GB on Facebook, 3GB on YouTube, 500MB on streaming protocols, 2GB web usage, 20MB VoIP calls, 3GB on BitTorrent, 200MB on updates etc.) (per device or total, it's not a problem)

And optionally:

• Most visited URLs/websites 
• Traffic per protocol (ICMP, TCP, UDP, HTTP/HTTPS, NTP, SMTP, etc.)

Really thank you in advance for your time!